# Error unzip my file in "C:\\Program Files (x86)" , No permissions

Tags: c#

i am doing a project that unzips a .zip file to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)". 
It returns the error :

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in Ionic.Zip.dll*

I search a lot but i can´t understand a way to resolve this problem.
Help me please .

My code :

```
namespace UTAD__VPN_w7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void buscarpasta()
        {
            DialogResult result = this.folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                /*string pedro = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                string pedro2 = pedro.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
                textBox1.Text = pedro2;*/
                string pasta1 = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                var pasta2 = pasta1.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                textBox1.Text = pasta2;

            }
        }

        private void MyExtract()
        {


            string zipToUnpack = "C:\\Users\\Zé Eduardo\\Music\\Cisco.zip";
            string unpackDirectory = textBox1.Text;
            using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
            {
                // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
                // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
                foreach (ZipEntry e in zip1)
                {

                    e.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
        }





        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buscarpasta();




        }
}
```

I get the path with the folderbrowserdialog1 and then i unzip clicking the button 1

Comment: The folder "C:\program files (x86)" is protected by the Operating System. You cannot (usually) write there

Comment: This is system folder and your application has to be ran with administrator privileges to write to it. Try to unzip to MyDocuments folder for example.

Comment: Yes , but how can the other program installers install in that path? I am looking for a code that let my write in that path

Comment: For more than a decade, writing to `C:\Program Files` has been restricted for non-administrators. Search for `[windows] UAC` and `[windows] privileges` here (or on Google without the `[]` characters, and you'll find thousands of results that explain exactly what the problem is and what needs to be done to work properly with UAC and privileges.

Comment: @JoséPedroBrito To ran the installer you have to be an administrator. The installer then automatically runs with administrator's privileges.

Comment: Ok , i will search more guys :)

Comment: I think you will need to elevate your credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program probably needs to be run with elevated permissions (e.g., as Administrator).  Check out the MSDN documentation for creating a manifest that marks your app as requiring elevation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756973.aspx).   The gist is this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your `Visual Studio` as an `Administrator`. This is if the application is not intended for external use.

You can also modify your app.config as suggested in the other answer in order to avoid user related issues.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>
```

Comment: It will solve my problem? And if i want to run my software in another computer , I am searching for a code that turn on the permissions with code.

Comment: @JoséPedroBrito The user on another computer will have to have the administrator's rights to write to that folder as well.

Comment: -1, this suggestion will make the problem worse because it will work for the programmer but not for the user.

Comment: This is almost always a bad idea - it's insecure, and you'll end up with intermediate build files which cannot be cleaned up by your normal account.  But if you are testing a program that needs administrative access, you'll need to do something.  It might be more proper to compile and then separately run the result as administrator.  Running the debugger is probably a bad idea - consider testing the task with another target directory?

Comment: @JohnMGant I only suggested that in the context of this being used internally by the programmer. I have updated with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

If the data you are unzipping belongs to your application, a better place to store that data might be in the directory given by

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

It looks like you are dealing with music files, in which case you might want to consider the MyMusic directory instead.

There is a list of the [system special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). Using them will ensure your program will work on different versions of Windows and, if you use the appropriate folder, there will be no problem with filesystem permissions.